# Using Count and Group By with Doctrine2 ,Symfony2 and AliDataBundle

Tags: symfony, datatable, doctrine-orm

I have an entity with three fields (id, user, location).
I want to display the number of users by location.

With SQL it's very easy, but I have an error when i want to use DQL and AliDatatableBundle

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('a')
->select("count(*) as myCount, a.location")->groupBy('a.location');
```

> 'myCount' does not point to a Class.

I've seen that AliDataBundle can use alias. It's should works.

Any Ideas ?

Comment: Have you try count(a.id) istead of using * ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one in your entity repository:

```
public function getSth() {
    $query = 'your sql query here';
    $em = $this->getEntityManager();
    $connection = $em->getConnection();

    $stmt = $connection->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute();

    return $stmt->fetchAll();
}
```

Or by query builder:

```
public function getSth() {
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder();
    $qb->select('count(a.id)');
    $qb->from('YourBundleBundle:Entity','a');
    $qb->groupBy('a.location');
    $query = $qb->getQuery();

    return $query->->execute();
}
```